# What does the "$" character mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables, dollar-sign, load-path

Been playing with Ruby on Rails for awhile and decided to take a look through the actual source. Grabbed the repo from GitHub and started looking around. Came across some code that I am not sure what it does or what it references.

I saw this code in actionmailer/test/abstract_unit.rb

```
root = File.expand_path('../../..', __FILE__)
 begin
 require "#{root}/vendor/gems/environment"
 rescue LoadError
 $:.unshift("#{root}/activesupport/lib")
 $:.unshift("#{root}/actionpack/lib")
end

lib = File.expand_path("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../lib")
$:.unshift(lib) unless $:.include?('lib') || $:.include?(lib)

require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'

require 'action_mailer'
require 'action_mailer/test_case'
```

Can someone tell me what the $: (a.k.a. "the bling") is referencing?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`$:` is the global variable used for looking up external files.

From https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/globals_rdoc.html

> `$LOAD_PATH` - Load path for searching Ruby scripts and extension libraries used by `Kernel#load` and `Kernel#require`. Aliased to `$:` and `$-I`

Answer (score 75):

`$` identifies a global variable, as opposed to a local variable, @instance variable, or @@class variable.

Among the language-supplied global variables are `$:`, which is also identified by `$LOAD_PATH`

Answer (score 9):

I wanna note something weird about Ruby!

`$` does indeed mean load path. And `;` means "end line". But!

`$;` means field separator. Try running `$;.to_s` in your REPL and you'll see it return `","`. That's not all! [`$` with other suffixes can mean many other things](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html).

Why? [Well, Perl of course!](http://ruby.wikia.com/wiki/Special_variable)

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for i.e. the use of $ in defining field separators among many other things.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the [Ruby Forum:](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142378)

ruby comes with a set of predefined variables

```
$: = default search path (array of paths)
__FILE__ = current sourcefile
```

if i get it right (not 100% sure) this adds the lib path to this array 
of search paths by going over the current file. which is not exactly the 
best way, i would simply start with RAILS_ROOT (at least for a rails 
project)

Answer (score 3):

```
$:.unshift
```

is the same as

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift
```

. You can also say:

```
$: <<
$LOAD_PATH <<
```

They are pretty common Ruby idioms to set a load path.