# Ruby on rails. ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 5)). Header should match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments

I'm sure this is something stupid but it's kicking my ass. I'm getting ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 5)) but the header and the method call match as far as I can see.

Error Page (Photo)
[image: Image of error]
Error Page (Text, Same as photo)

```
ArgumentError in MessageServiceController#put
wrong number of arguments (1 for 5)
Extracted source (around line #14):


end
def storeMessage(from_host, to_host, service, message, arguments)
$fh = from_host
$th = to_host

Rails.root: -------------------------
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/helpers/message_service_helper.rb:14:in `storeMessage'
app/controllers/message_service_controller.rb:20:in `put'

Request

Parameters:

{"message"=>"9,
9,
9,
9,
9,
9"}

Started GET "/message_service/put?message=9,9,9,9,9,9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-01 14:04:53 +0000
Processing by MessageServiceController#put as HTML
  Parameters: {"message"=>"9,9,9,9,9,9"}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 5)):
  app/helpers/message_service_helper.rb:14:in `storeMessage'
  app/controllers/message_service_controller.rb:22:in `put'
```

This is my controller where the call is made.

```
class MessageServiceController < ApplicationController
  include MessageServiceHelper

  def put

    $messageSplit = params[:message].split(",")

    $to_host = $messageSplit[0]
    $from_host = $messageSplit[1]
    $service = $messageSplit[2]
    $message = $messageSplit[3]
    $arguments = $messageSplit[4]

    storeMessage(from_host:$from_host, to_host:$to_host, service:$service, message:$message, arguments:$arguments)

    render :layout => false
  end
```

This is my helper where the method is implemented. I have other methods in the same helper that are called from the same controller without issue.

```
  def storeMessage(from_host, to_host, service, message, arguments)

    Message.create(from_host:from_host, to_host:to_host, service:service, message:message, arguments:arguments)

  end
```

I can't see any problem but I've been trying to figure this out for a day. Note I have looked at the other questions about wrong number of arguments and they seem to be different issues.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error says you are giving one argument to a method that expects five: `storeMessage` is defined as requiring five parameters, but when you call it on your controller, you are passing only **one Hash**:

```
storeMessage(from_host:$from_host, to_host:$to_host, service:$service, message:$message, arguments:$arguments)
```

Change your call like this:

```
storeMessage($from_host, $to_host, $service, $message, $arguments)
```

And you'll see the error go away.

From your code, I think you are mixing Ruby syntax with other language's such as, maybe, PHP. I suggest you have a look at the [Ruby](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) style guides. More precisely, you are defining all your variables in your controller [as global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896876/what-does-the-character-mean-in-ruby) (with `$`), which I'm quite sure that you don't need/want to do.