# What does this ruby operator mean $?

Tags: ruby, system

What does the `$?` Ruby operator mean?

I know that it is used for system calls and can be used to tell if a system call was successful.

I tried searching for documentation but couldn't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1896876/5647260 - See 2nd answer

Comment: Look in the [English documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html) in the STDLIB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `$` operator. `$` is used to prefix global variables. What you're thinking of as an operator is actually just a bunch of predefined global variables that Ruby provides for you, which happen to have odd names like `$!` and `$:`.

See http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html

Comment: There's a dupe for that.

Comment: why would you being a moderator answer such question instead of locking it as duplication? :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Because I was unaware of the dupe?

Comment: Hm, could be. But I doubt there is at least single more or less seasoned SO user (and you are definitely one of those  big users) with Ruby background who would not think this was asked before. (downvote's not mine)