# What is $, (dollar comma)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I see it's used in `safe_join` https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/safe_join

in irb it returns `nil`

```
irb(main):001:0> $,
=> nil
```

Comment: I don't have the answer but `$11123` and `$abc` are also nil.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896876/what-does-the-character-mean-in-ruby

Comment: I know $ is for global variables,  but it seems to be special one

Comment: @nita: Well, `$11123` is the 11123rd positional parameter of your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$,`  is the separarator output between the arguments to `print` and the default separarator for `Array.join`. It is `nil` by default. [Globals](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html)

Comment: Thanks, should have looked at `Array#join`, https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join

Comment: Note that it is also by `print`. Example: `$,='x'; print 5,6;`

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully, [the magic global variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html) are now properly documented. According to this documentation, `$,` is

> The output field separator for [`Kernel#print`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-print) and [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join).

That means the value of `$,` is the value that is used by `Kernel#print` and by `Array#join` as the default value for joining multiple elements. The default value of `$,` at startup is `nil`, which means that there is no separator between elements.